# Ver página como otro usuario en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy desarrollando un sistema con Laravel 5.3 que tiene distintas secciones y roles. Para probar dichos roles me gustaría poder tener una ruta que me permita cambiar de usuario sin estar deslogueandome y cambiando de usuario o cambiando mis roles.

Lo que quiero vendría ser como tiene Facebook que te deja ver tu muro como un usuario específico.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrias que hacer un controlador que lo gestione, por ejemplo

```
Route::get('fakeuser/{id}', 'FakeuserController@fakelogin');
```

y en el controlador autentificarlo de forma manual, cabe destacar el problema de seguridad que esto significa. No estoy 100% seguro de que funcione ya que depende mucho del tipo de autenticación que uses, pero puedes considerarlo un punto de referencia.

```
       $user = User::findOrFail($id);
       if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $user->email, 'password' => $user->password])) {
            return redirect()->intended('home');
        }
```